# Интерполяция выражений

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Начал изучать JS.
Почему не работают выражения в строке htmlCode?

```js
function generateColor() {
 return "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
}

function circle() {
 var r = Math.random() * 100 + 50,
      d = r * 2,
      color = generateColor(),
      htmlCode = '<div style="width: ${d}px; height: ${d}px; background-color: ${color}; border-radius: 50%;"></div>';
  document.write(htmlCode);
}
circle();
```

Comment: А откуда у Вас вообще взялась идея, будто такое выражение в строке: `${d}` должно как-то "работать"?

Comment: См. заголовок "Интерполяция выражений" https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Comment: А, ну так шаблонные-то строки заключаются в обратные апострофы, а не в простые.

Comment: так как должно быть правильно, чтоб работало?)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените ' на `:

```js
function generateColor() {
 return "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
}

function circle() {
 var r = Math.random() * 100 + 50,
      d = r * 2,
      color = generateColor(),
      htmlCode = `<div style="width: ${d}px; height: ${d}px; background-color: ${color}; border-radius: 50%;"></div>`;
  document.write(htmlCode);
}
circle();
```

Comment: Вот я дал)))))) А мне казалось, что это простой апостроф на Э